# What is the meaning of the phrase "all the more impressive"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence, phrase-meaning

> **Vestager has a reputation for toughness, stemming from her time as economics minister and deputy prime minister in Denmark.** She managed to push through the Radikale Venstre party’s centrist agenda in the face of strong opposition, earning her another nickname: “Margrethe III” — implying she was almost as powerful as Danish Queen Margrethe II and had more political influence than the then-prime minister.
>
> Over her career, the 47-year-old has racked up a laundry list of accomplishments, from becoming Denmark’s youngest-ever female minister to being its first politician to give birth while serving in cabinet.
>
> So it’s **all the more impressive** she comes across as sweet, polite, open and thoughtful — the kind of politician you could share a sandwich with.

What does the phrase **all the more impressive** mean? Are the words of that phrase in the correct sequence? How does it function in the sentence/passage?

[quote here](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/meet-denmarks-iron-lady-who-could-cost-google-66-billion-2015-06-25)

Comment: It means that you omitted critical context leading up to the above statement.  Eg, she may, in secret, be a cannibal who eats small children and tortures cute little kittens, making her apparent behavior "impressive" in contrast.

Comment: With the link to the article, there's plenty of context, and with that context, it's clear your suggestion is right on target. The implication is that she's a _wolf in sheep's clothing; a silver-tongued devil; a siren luring the unwary to their destruction_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it makes more sense to you, there is an implied `that` after the word impressive.

> So it’s all the more impressive **that** she comes across as sweet, polite, open and thoughtful — the kind of politician you could share a sandwich with.

By `all the more impressive`, the writer is saying that there is a negative connotation about a type of person that that person overcame. Think about a politician. They are known to be charismatic and deceptive. Therefore, it would be impressive for a politician to be that *and* polite, sweet, open, and thoughtful.

Another example would be an orphan or an immigrant, people that start with nothing. It would be all the more impressive if they became rich or famous because of that.